# can not create collation in postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I can not create collation in postgresql.

```
CREATE COLLATION french (LOCALE = 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
ERROR:  could not create locale "fr_FR.UTF-8": Success
```

I did `sudo locale_get fr_FR.utf-8` which is done. could someone help me?

Comment: Try to restart PostgreSQL after `locale_gen`.

Comment: It works after restarted postgresql. Thanks.